# Cannot convert value of type 'NSLocale' to type 'Locale' in coercion while changing calendar Georgian to Persian

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, calendar

I am trying to convert `Georgian Calendar` to `Persian Calendar` using:

```
dateAndTimePicker.calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.persian)! as Calendar!
dateAndTimePicker.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fa_IR") as Locale
```

The calendar is converted accordingly but giving error on 2nd line while changing the language of calender and time picker:

[image]

After changing this:

```
dateAndTimePicker.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fa_IR") as Locale
```

to:

```
dateAndTimePicker.locale = Locale.init(Identifier: "fa_IR")
```

this error appears:

[image: error]

For datepicker, I have made an outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dateAndTimePicker: UIDatePicker!
```

Comment: Replace `Identifier` with `identifier` in `dateAndTimePicker.locale = Locale.init(Identifier: "fa_IR")`

Comment: Case matters: `identifier`, not `Identifier`.

Comment: No it does not in this case. Tried that as well.

Comment: Of course case matters. Swift is a case sensitive language. It's `Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")`, not `Locale(Identifier: "fa_IR")`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `NSLocale` now you can replace

```
dateAndTimePicker.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fa_IR") as Locale
```

with

```
dateAndTimePicker.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "fa_IR")
```

Comment: Now it gives this error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Comment: Latest one. 9.4.1.

Comment: Updated. Please check and guide.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to create `NSCalendar`. Please create swift variable and use as below

```
    let calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.persian)!
    let locale = Locale.init(identifier: "fa_IR")
    dateAndTimePicker.calendar = calendar
    dateAndTimePicker.locale = locale
```

Comment: Now it gives this error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Comment: what is your "dateAndTimePicker" var? Show its declaration

Comment: Please update calender and locale as i answered and just build. Don't use NSCalender or NSLocale. Replace with my answered and build.

Comment: Hey I found error in your syntax...check spelling of identifier...you wrote Identifier so error is occured

Comment: No Rakesh its not spelling issue

Comment: And I have tried your way. Not working. Samee error on same line.

Comment: code is working at my side...I is capital you have to make in small latter.. check..spelling is correct